# How do I fade text in and out with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code: I want to have the var text crossfade basically.

JS:

```
var text = ["ease your mind.", "focus.", "sleep better."];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
setInterval(change, 2000);
function change() {
 elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
    counter++;
    if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
}
```

HTML:

```
<span id="changeText" class="italic bold">ease your mind.</span>
```

Comment: You should at least show some code where you tried to implement the fading.

Comment: If you don't want to fade out the element, wrap the text in a span or div, use `fadeOut()`, change the text and then use `fadeIn()`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/txLwssur/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `$.fadeIn` and `$.fadeOut`:

```js
var text = ["ease your mind.", "focus.", "sleep better."];
var counter = 1;
var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
setInterval(change, 2000);

function change() {
    $(elem).fadeOut(400, function() {
        $(elem).html(text[counter++]).fadeIn(400);
        if (counter >= text.length) counter = 0;
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="changeText" class="italic bold">ease your mind.</span>
```

Comment: This works but why does it show sleep better twice in a row?

Comment: Oops.  I used `++counter` rather than `counter++`, with `counter` initialized to `0`.  I fixed it now.